# MS Outlook 2010 - Exporting a folder

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Hi I am trying to export emails in a  folder and I used the export function but it did not have date and time which I need to import into a CRM. I managed to do an export using MS Access and it includes the date/time of the email but the From only has the senders name and not the email. There are 2 from fields one should have the name the other the email but both have only names. Any ideas would be welcome.

Thanks

Simon

Answer (score 0):

Try our **free** [Export Messages to EML Format](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookMessagesExportEML/) and [Export Messages to MSG Format](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookMessagesExportMSG) utilities. They both save every single piece of data including names and emails. I recommend these tools because I'm one of the developers.